# Finding midpoint of string in R (mid character of a word)

Tags: r

I'd like to find the midpoint of any word after the following is done to the word:

```
>x = 'hello'
>y = strsplit(x, '')
>y
[[1]]
[1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"
>z = unlist(y)
>z
[1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"
```

Doing this then allows for :

```
> z[1]
[1] "h"
> z[4]
[1] "l"
```

The difference being that before `z=unlist(y)` when you try `z[index]` you get back `NA`, example:

```
> x = 'hello'
> strsplit(x, '')
[[1]]
[1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o"
> x[1]
[1] "hello"
> x[2]
[1] NA
```

Anyways, what I want to do is find the mid point of words that are in this format so that the output would be something like:

```
"l"
```

in the case of the word "hello". Also, in this example we have a word with 5 letters allowing to easily designate a single character as the midpoint but for a word like "bake" I would like to designate both "a" and "k" together as the midpoint.

Comment: @Dason: The OP specified that the middle two letters should be chosen in that case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
f1 <- function(str1){
    N <- nchar(str1)
     if(!N%%2){
      res <- substr(str1, N/2, (N/2)+1) 
     }
     else{

   N1 <- median(sequence(N))
   res <- substr(str1, N1, N1)
    }
   res
  }

f1('bake')
#[1] "ak"
f1('hello')
#[1] "l"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option.  `get_middle` assumes the word has already been split into characters, as per your description:

```
get_middle <- function(x) {
  mid <- (length(x) + 1) / 2
  x[unique(c(ceiling(mid), floor(mid)))]
}
```

Then:

```
words <- c("bake", "hello")
lapply(strsplit(words, ""), get_middle)
```

Produces:

```
[[1]]
[1] "k" "a"

[[2]]
[1] "l"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
midpoint <- function(word) {
    # Split the word into a vector of letters
    split <- strsplit(word, "")[[1]]

    # Get the number of letters in the word
    n <- nchar(word)

    # Get the two middle letters for words of even length,
    # otherwise get the single middle letter
    if (n %% 2 == 0) {
        c(split[n/2], split[n/2+1])
    } else {
        split[ceiling(n/2)]
    }
}
```

In the case of a word of even length, the middle two characters are returned as a vector.

```
midpoint("hello")
#[1] "l"

midpoint("bake")
#[1] "a" "k"
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
mid<-function(str)substr(str,(nchar(str)+1)%/%2,(nchar(str)+2)%/%2)
```

Or slightly more legibly:

```
mid2<-function(str){
  n1<-nchar(str)+1
  substr(str,n1%/%2,(n1+1)%/%2)
}

> mid("bake")
[1] "ak"
> mid("hello")
[1] "l"
```

This has the advantage that it immediately vectorizes:

```
> mid(c("bake","hello"))
[1] "ak" "l"
```

It is slower than @akrun's solution for long words, but my second version is faster; apparently counting characters can be costly for longer strings.

If you want the final product in a list, you can just `strsplit` the result:

```
mid3<-function(str)strsplit(mid2(str),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
word = c("bake","hello")
print(nchar(word))
q = ifelse (nchar(word)%%2==0, substr(word,nchar(word)/2,nchar(word)/2+1),substr(word,nchar(word)/2+1,nchar(word)/2+1))
print(q)

[1] 4 5
[1] "ak" "l"
```